# Use Scalaz >> and >>= in the same expression

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz

In Haskell I use often `>>=`  and `>>` to compose monadic actions. For example:

```
> Just 1 >>= Just . (+1) >> Just ()
Just ()
```

In Scala there is only flatMap, so I decided to use Scalaz `>>=` and `>>`. The problem is that I have an error with the code:

```
> 1.some >>= { i:Int => (i+1).some } >> ().some
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Option[Unit]
 required: Int => ?
          1.some >>= { i:Int => (i+1).some } >> ().some
                                                   ^
```

I was sure the above expression was equal to

```
1.some.>>=({ i:Int => (i+1).some }).>>(().some)
```

but this works as expected. I think scalac interprets the code as

```
1.some >>= ({ i:Int => (i+1).some } >> ().some)
```

that is obviously wrong because of the type of `>>`. I'm right on the interpretation? If yes, what are the syntactic rules involved? If I still want to use `>>=` and `>>` in the same expression, the best solution is to wrap `arg1 >>= arg2` inside parenthesys? Like:

```
(1.some >>= { i:Int => (i+1).some }) >> ().some
```

Comment: See section 6.12.3 http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf `• If there are consecutive inﬁx operations e0 op1
e1 op2
...opn
en with operators
op1
, ..., opn of the same precedence, then all these operators must have the
same associativity` so `>>=` and `>>` must have the same associativity since infix precedence for them is the same.